# While profile updation getting error in swift using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to update the profile through .GET method. If I use any space in any field between characters on any field its has error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.But the same URL working fine if I test it on Postman, successfully updated. so through application why it is creating error in Alamofire .

```
 @IBAction func btnSavePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    Firstname = txtFName.text!
    Lastname = txtLname.text!
    Username = txtUname.text!
    Phone = Int(txtPhone.text!)
    DoorNo = txtDoorNo.text!
    Street = txtStreet.text!
    Town = txtTown.text!
    Postcode = Int(txtPostCode.text!)

    print(Firstname)
    print(Lastname)
    print(Username)
    print(Phone)
    print(DoorNo)
    print(Street)
    print(Town)
    print(Postcode)
    print("http://\(platform).eposapi.co.uk/?app_id=\(apiID)&app_key=\(apikey)&request=\(request)&id=\(UserID)&fname=\(Firstname)&lname=\(Lastname)&phone=\(Phone)&dno=\(DoorNo)&add1=\(Street)&add2=\(Town)&postcode=\(Postcode)")

    UPDATE_data_from_URl()
}

 func UPDATE_data_from_URl(){

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://\(platform).eposapi.co.uk/?app_id=\(apiID)&app_key=\(apikey)&request=\(request)&id=\(UserID)&fname=\(Firstname)&lname=\(Lastname)&phone=\(Phone)&dno=\(DoorNo)&add1=\(Street)&add2=\(Town)&postcode=\(Postcode)", parameters: nil )
        .responseJSON {
            response in
            print(response)

            if let result: AnyObject = response.result.value {

                let post: JSON = JSON(result)

                let action = post["action"].boolValue
                let info = post["info"].stringValue
                print(action)
                print(info)

                if action == false{
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: info, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else{
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: info, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
                        (action) in



                        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourtabbarvcidentifier") as! UITabBarController
                        vc.selectedIndex = 0
                        self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)


                        })
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: use the other API, `Alamofire.request(.GET, baseUrl, parameters: yourParamsHere, encoding: .URLEncoded, headers:nil)` this will make the url etc work for you with even spaces

Comment: but  there is no POST method.so here in parameters what should i use here@Shubhank

Comment: i have shown you the GET method only which you have in your question

Comment: check your valid is empty

Comment: while using GET how could i pass parameters.. I only have pass parameters in POSTmethod. give some idea @Shubhank

Comment: you can pass the parameters in GET request too, that is why the option `encoding: .URLEncoded`. if you will try this code. you will understand it. More you can ask in chat room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to remove white space from your string then try it.

```
let linkString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=\(Location!)"
let address = NSURL(string:linkString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: ""))!
```